# Python / Spyder - Undefined variable error, when variable is defined and shown in the environment. Code works even with the error

Tags: python, environment-variables, spyder, pyflakes, undefined-variable

I am getting a strange error when defining variables in Python 4.1.5 (IDE:Spyder). **However, even with the error, the code runs without any issues!**

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the variable `social_cost_of_carbon` is stored as a variable, but I keep getting that error as show in picture 1 **(the error writes: Undefined name 'social_cost_of_carbon' (Pyflakes E)**

I feel that the way that i declare those variables might be the reason:

```
def convert_to_var(df):
    desc = []
    val = []  
    
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        desc.append(i)
        val.append(row) 
        
    return dict(val)

val_dict = convert_to_var(IA)
locals().update(val_dict)
```

Since the code runs without any problems, I am not doing anything to resolve this. Do I need to worry and fix this, or do I just let it be and continue without dealing with the error since the code runs smoothly?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) As you guessed, the problem is that you're creating your variable dynamically with this line in your code:

```
locals().update(val_dict)
```

Since our linter can't find where that variable is properly declared, it reports that it's undefined. But it's safe for you to ignore that message.

*Note*: Since Spyder 5.1.0, you can avoid the linter error by adding a comment at the end of the problematic line of the form `# noqa`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Carlos, it really clear things up. Do you have an expectation of when this future version will be available?

Comment: Most probably in our 4.2.2 version, to be released in February 2021.

Comment: Excellent - would love to see the little red dots disappear from my code =]

Comment: I was presuming that, that's why I left my note at the end.

Comment: It works in Spyder 5.4.2. noqa = No Quality Assurance

Comment: @David, that's correct. I updated my answer to reflect that.